# Firefox Input Styling Across Versions

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox 19.0.2, an `input` tag using the browsers styling agent has the following layout:

[image]

In Firefox 18.0.1, the same `input` has this layout:

[image]

As you can see the padding, border-width and width properties have all changed.

Considering the amount of sites utilizing a fixed position layout, is this a poor design decision?  I'm assuming a large volume of sites will break when viewed in FF19.

Is this a common problem with new versions?  Is there an approach to handle this issue?

Comment: Does not seem to be the case on Windows 7 with default theme. What's your environment?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario is the OS going to affect the browsers styling agent?

Comment: That's the traditional problem when styling form controls, isn't it?

Comment: The environment I'm using is Windows XP & Windows 7, I thought a browser would just use its own native styling regardless of the OS.

Comment: Whatever, that change probably comes from your own CSS (unstyled `<input>` fields haven't changed for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is but one browser, and 19 is but one version of that browser.  Compare those styles with styles of other browsers and you'll surely see differences.

There are browser reset libraries ([take your pick](http://www.cssreset.com/)) to rectify this very issue -- not just when a single browser changes between versions, but also for IE vs FF vs Chrome vs Safari vs...